# Reference request for symplectic geometry.

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, symplectic-geometry

I wish to start learning symplectic geometry. I have taken a course in differential geometry of curves and surfaces, another in differentiable manifolds and another in algebraic topology.

Please mention some books that one would take up as the first reference to symplectic geometry.

Also, please mention any supplementary texts or materials one would need apart from a knowledge of differentiable manifolds to learn symplectic geometry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ana Cannas da Silva's lecture notes on Symplectic Geometry, available [here](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~acannas/Papers/lsg.pdf), are a good first reference.

In addition to differentiable manifolds and linear algebra, you will need to know some exterior algebra (familiarity with multilinear forms and tensors). The notes also assume familiarity with de Rham cohomology.